# Facebook login works only once

Tags: javascript, facebook

I try to load a page with on there the facebook login code with

```
$('#pagecontent').load
```

This works very well but works only one time when all pages are loaded.
If i try to load it for the second time then

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
```

Not fire up for the second time.
Is there a way to do this ?

something like

```
document.fbAsyncInit = function()
```

I not want want to reload all the pages all the time or to work with iframe
because the fb login itself is already loading very slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code to embed the JS SDK is specifically written in a way that will not load it a second time.

If you want it to go through the document again to look for elements to parse into social plugins/Facebook buttons, after content has been added dynamically, you need to call [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/).